# "Index out of range" when removing last item in QAbstractTableModel

Tags: qt

I implemented the `removeRows()` method according to the documentation. My data is stored in a QList. I can remove items just fine using:

```
bool MeasurementManager::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &m) {
    if(count > 1) {
        qDebug() << "MeasurementManager: cannot remove more than one measurement";
        return false;
    }

    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row+count-1);
    list.removeAt(row);
    endRemoveRows();
    return true
}
```

However, when removing the last item I get the following error message, when executing `beginRemoveRows()`:

`ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range"`

When removing the last item (leading to the crash) it obviously has to be in row 0, but as long as there are other items in the model I can remove the item in row 0 without any problems.

If I comment out the actual removal of my data like this

```
beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row+count-1);
//list.removeAt(row);
endRemoveRows();
```

no crash occurs, so my assumption it, that something tries to access one of list's elements after the removal. However when stepping through the function the `beginRemoveRows()` method clearly is the culprit.

Any help where to start debugging would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, my bad. I had connected to the ´selectionChanged()´ signal to a custom slot. This tried to access the recently deleted item in the table model.

I overlooked, that deselection a table item emits an `selectionChanged()` signal, too.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is probably an artifact of code reordering introduced by optimizing the code.

Compile the code again with all optimizations disabled to avoid confusing the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. Simply call reset() and remove the rows afterwards.

```
void QItemSelectionModel::reset() [virtual slot]
Clears the selection model. Does not emit any signals.
```